# ¿Qué porcentaje de pedidos no son surtidos en su totalidad? en oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, mi consulta en oracle debe resolver la dice la siguiente pregunta
¿Qué porcentaje de pedidos no son surtidos en su totalidad?

con esta consulta me salen los pedidos que no son surtidos por completo los cuales son 3592

```
select count(*) as nosurtidos from pedidodetalle  where cantidadsolicitada<>cantidadsurtida;
```

y con la siguiente consulta me dicen cuantos registros tengo en la tabla los cuales son 45257

```
select count(*) as total from pedidodetalle ;
```

por lo tanto para que me muestre algo debe de ser el numero 7.93 pero no entiendo muy bien como lo debo realizar (esta sentencia la hice pero no funciona)

```
select concat((nosurtidos*100)/count(*),'%') as porcentaje from(select count(*) as nosurtidos from pedidodetalle where cantidadsolicitada<>cantidadsurtida) order by;
```

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al parecer count(*) te da el valor =1 ya que te esta devoliendo el count de pedidodetalle en nosurtidos:

intente aplicarle una subconsulta en en vez del count(*)
ejemplo:

```
select concat((nosurtidos*100)/(select count(*) as total from pedidodetalle),'%') as porcentaje from(select count(*) as nosurtidos from pedidodetalle where cantidadsolicitada<>cantidadsurtida);
```

o puede ser de la siguiente manera:

```
select concat((count(*)*100)/(select count(*) as total from pedidodetalle),'%') as porcentaje from pedidodetalle where cantidadsolicitada<>cantidadsurtida;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es realizar las consultas por separado para construir la respuesta, con la división de lo devuelto por cada sub-consulta. Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como:

```
select (
        select count(1) 
          from pedidodetalle  
         where cantidadsolicitada <> cantidadsurtida
       ) / (
        select count(1) 
          from pedidodetalle
       ) 
  from dual;
```